# How to pass data from a Rules Action to a subsequent Rules Action?

Tags: 7, rules, actions

How I can add actions in the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module in which they have a relationship with each other sequentially.

I mean a 1st Rules Action sequentially passes data to a next Rules Action and in that next Rules Action I can use those passed data from previous data.

[image]

Comment: what you mean " they have a relationship with each sequentially" ?  you want pass data from action1 to action2 ?

Comment: Yes! Can you help me alright

Answer (score 0):

I think you can pass data with `Variables` , in one action set variable(s) and in next action get that variable(s),this have one bug if concurrent event occur data will return mistake values, a solution for this is using unique variable name per user(or action), I get you a clue (maybe you get idea from it)

**in Action1**
set Php action

```
 global $user;
 // some job here 
 // $result= .....
 variable_set("action1_result-".$user->uid, $result);
```

**in Action2**
set Php action

```
 global $user;
 variable_get("action1_result-".$user->uid);
```

Comment: I will try to apply what you say. Thank you very much

Comment: @LêQuangTú you're welcome :)

Comment: good idea vote up

Answer (score 0):

***Assumption***:

Your rule has 2 Rules Actions (Action 1 and Action 2). And you want to pass "some data" created by Action 1 as input to Action 2.

***Solution***:

1. Create a Rules Component which does the same as "Action 1", say you name it "*RulesComponentAction1*".
2. Create a Rules Component which does the same as "Action 2", say you name it "*RulesComponentAction2*".
3. Adapt your original rule so that you replace Action1 in it by the execution of Rules Component named *RulesComponentAction1*.
4. Adapt your original rule so that you replace Action2 in it by the execution of Rules Component named *RulesComponentAction2*.
5. Improve your *RulesComponentAction1*, by adding within its *Settings* an extra variable with `Usage=Provided` (and whatever Data Type that fits your needs). Say you name it `VarFromAction1`.
6. Improve your *RulesComponentAction2*, by adding within its *Settings* an extra variable with `Usage=Parameter` (and a Data Type that matches the data type you selected in the previous step). Say you name it  `VarForAction2`
7. Adapt your original rule so that you pass the extra parameter `VarForAction2` to your Rules Component *RulesComponentAction2*, using as a token ... you guessed it ... the value of `VarFromAction1`.

**Note**: By using the [Rules Session Variables](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_session_vars) module you might be able to further extend the above solution to 2 separate rules that get executed one after the other.